# Need a cleaner way, which avoids too many 'if statements', to write this method for inputing data into datastore entity attributes?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the best way to reference datastore model attributes without using the four `'if statements'` I have in the below sample code, which seem messy and inefficient. For real-world code I may have a situation of 100 attributes such as `self.var1, self.var2, ... self.varN` that I want to some how reference with just an integer (or strings) as an argument to some method.

```
class PixelObject(db.Model):

 zoom0 = db.ListProperty(int)
 zoom1 = db.ListProperty(int)
 zoom2 = db.ListProperty(int)
 zoom3 = db.ListProperty(int)
 zoom4 = db.ListProperty(int)

 def inputZoomData(self, zoomInteger, input_data):
        """input_data goes to specified attribute based on if 0,1,2,3,or 4 is argument"""

  if zoomInteger == 0: self.zoom0 = input_data
  if zoomInteger == 1: self.zoom1 = input_data
  if zoomInteger == 2: self.zoom2 = input_data
  if zoomInteger == 3: self.zoom3 = input_data
  if zoomInteger == 4: self.zoom4 = input_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also recommend using an array instead of five members to simplify your code:

```
if 0 <= zoomInteger < len(zooms):
    self.zooms[zoomInteger] = input_data
else:
    # Error handling.
```

If you can't change the way the class is designed another alternative is to use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(self, 'zoom' + str(zoomInteger), input_data)
```

Comment: The 2nd answer is perfect..Thanks! 

Since I app engine cant have a list of lists in the ListProperty attribute of a datastore model I cant use the 1st answer.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to achieve, we can suggest a better way of representing your data.

Answer (score 2):

How about using an array of integers, instead of holding five different integer properties?

Comment: App Engine Model's cannot have lists stored with a ListProperty attribute so to mimic an array ( or a list of lists) I need to have many attributes where each is a ListProperty.